# Linux: Nonexistent Directory Exists Bug after failed SFTP attempt?

Tags: linux, sftp, putty, file-transfer, access-rights

So, I've been administrating a personal game server in Linux so far (bear in mind, I don't possess the physical server - I have shell access, including root). I am relatively inexperienced with remote Linux administration. I made an attempt to transfer a directory titled 'mods' to this server which contains several other directories and files. I have successfully SFTP'd into this server before and transferred files before, but this time for whatever reasons transfers were failing and so I stopped the transfers.

Upon refreshing the directory, in FileZilla, I see a new folder with the name ". Yes, just ". Deleting or attempting to modify this directory doesn't work even for root user. Linux says it doesn't exist or this happens...

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrZGL.png)

And also attempting to transfer files via SFTP now results in errors such as,

Error:  Directory  no such file or directory

Error:  mkdir 'remote server directory': received failure with description 'Failure'

Error:  get attrs for 'remote directory path'/'file name': no such file or directory

where 'remote server directory' or 'remote director path'/'file name' are names of the things to be transferred.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Usually people on Linux use `ls` to list directories rather than `dir`. `ls` will report the name as `'"'`, (`"` wrapped in single quotes) which is how you escape the name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux shell uses quotes `"some filename"` to surround command line parameters (similar to MS Windows). If a file name actually contains `"` as a character, you need to escape it:

```
~/example$ dir
~/example$ mkdir mods
~/example$ mkdir '"' # whoops!
~/example$ dir
"  mods
~/example$ rmdir \" # escape it
~/example$ dir
mods
~/example$ rmdir '"' # or wrap in single quotes
```